# Trying to create a histogram with ZedGraph

Tags: c#, histogram, zedgraph

I am trying to create a histogram with ZedGraph.

The bars and data are all good, the only thing needed is my bars to be between the tics instead of directly on the tics.

Sample data:

```
1, 4
2, 8
3, 1
```

Means that I have:

```
4 items that are >= 0 and < 1
8 items that are >= 1 and < 2
1 item that is >= 2 and < 3
```

So currently my bars are of course appearing directly on the tics (x values) 1, 2 and 3.

But I would like to see:

- the first bar between the tics 0 and 1,
- the second bar between the tics 1 and 2 and
- the third bar between the tics 2 and 3

What is the property to tweak in order to achieve that?
I am currently looking in `XAxis` and `XAxis.Scale`, but I haven't found anything yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can't do it with normal `BarItem`. I use the `BoxObj` objects to create the histogram.

If `histList` is the `PointPairList` containing your pairs of histogram values (breakpoint and value) you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < histList.Count - 1; i++)
{
BoxObj box = new BoxObj(histList[i].X, histList[i].Y, histList[i + 1].X - histList[i].X, histList[i].Y);
box.IsClippedToChartRect = true;
box.Fill.Color = myColor;
pane.GraphObjList.Add(box);
}
```

Using the `BoxObj` you have full control on where the bar is located etc. More info in [documentation](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_BoxObj.htm)

**EDIT**
Remember that when using `BoxObj` (or any `GraphObj` in general) the X and Y scales are not going to be set automatically. You need to set the scale ranges manually:

```
pane.XAxis.Scale.Min = ...
pane.XAxis.Scale.Max = ...
pane.YAxis.Scale.Min = ...
pane.YAxis.Scale.Max = ...
```

Comment: Hi, the chart starts zoomed up too much and many bars are outside of the visible area (zooming out we can see them). Would you be aware of how to fix it?